# snmpwalk v2 unknown token (centos)

Tags: centos, putty, snmp

I've installed opennms on centos7 but when trying to enable snmp on it I keep getting the unknown token errors. Such as comsec2, group, view, access.

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c 209ijvfwer0df92jd -O e 127.0.0.1
```

It shows the errors on the file, /etc/snmp/snmp.conf for lines: 4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 127

The vi file is shown below.

```
# Map 'idv90we3rnov90wer' community to the 'ConfigUser'
# Map '209ijvfwer0df92jd' community to the 'AllUser'
#       sec.name        source          community
com2sec ConfigUser      default         idv90we3rnov90wer
com2sec AllUser         default         209ijvfwer0df92jd
# Map 'ConfigUser' to 'ConfigGroup' for SNMP Version 2c
# Map 'AllUser' to 'AllGroup' for SNMP Version 2c
#                       sec.model       sec.name
group   notConfigGroup     v2c             notConfigUser
group   AllGroup        v2c             AllUser
# Define 'SystemView', which includes everything under .1.3.6.1.2.1.1       (or .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1)
# Define 'AllView', which includes everything under .1
#                       incl/excl       subtree
view    SystemView      included        .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view    SystemView      included        .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
view    AllView         included        .1
# Give 'ConfigGroup' read access to objects in the view 'SystemView'
# Give 'AllGroup' read access to objects in the view 'AllView'
#                       context model   level   prefix    read                   write   notify
access  ConfigGroup     ""      any     noauth  exact   SystemView        none    none
access  AllGroup        ""      any     noauth  exact   AllView         none    none
```

Answer (score 0):

None of those options belong to `snmp.conf`. Everything in your example are server-side settings that were meant to be put in the SNMP daemon's `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` instead.